# Get sum of two Metrics

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana, grafana, collectd

Get sum of metrics

Hello there,

I am currently working on a little project for my company. And now I am facing a problem where I have to get the sum of two metrics.

Currently I 4 metrics 2 of them are calculating the average rx and tx, and the other two metrics are calculation the derivative average from average rx and average tx.

The Derivative Average Rx has the value 3.3 and the derivative Average Tx has 3.4.

Now i need a query or a metric where i get the sum of this two Derivative Averages. Than it should show 6.7.

I'm using Grafana 7.1.5 and Kibana 7.9.0!

Thanks for your help

VallingSki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for this. In the .json file for the dashboard, you can tanke the id from your derivative average, and write it in the "pipelineAgg" from your variable. In my case I entered 4 for my var1, and 5 for my var2! Hope it helpes!